# Mezzanine and MySQL: unicode errors

Tags: mysql, django, mezzanine

During a mezzanine default setup (via `pip`) with the MySQL backend, I see unicode errors after I choose to install the included examples.

```
sudo pip install mezzanine
...
sudo -u mezzanine python manage.py createdb --noinput
```

This produces the following error, which traces back to 4-byte unicode entities.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xEF\\xBE\\x8C\\xE3\\x80\\x8D...' for column 'file' at row 1")
```

MySQL's default unicode only supports 3-byte entities. But when I go and set they tpe to utf8mb4 (the 4-byte MySQL UTF-8), I hit this error instead:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

The question is this: doesn't anyone use Mezzanine's examples with MySQL? If you do, how do they configure the database, and what version of Mezzanine and of  MySQL are you using?

Comment: does anyone use mezzanine at all. You get about 2 or 3 questions a week here.

Comment: Just to be clear -- I did not say no-one uses Mezzanine, to the contrary my working theory is that there *must* be folks who use Mezzanine with MySQL, so it seems odd that a default install of the built-in examples would fail... hence I am either using the wrong combination of versions or doing something else obviously wrong.

Comment: I was using Mezzanine 4.0.1 together with MySql 5.6 The only thing I can write in the moment that it was working at that moment.

Comment: but did you install the sample application? The errors seem to be all related to that sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: it is a bug. I fixed Mezzanine's configuration, got everything working with MySql 5.6, but those four four-byte unicode warnings persist **if you install the example site**.

As long as I do not have the DB in strict mode, where the warnings make the whole transaction fail and the install comes down crashing, this is fairly benign. A small bug, and there is room for finger pointing: Mezzanine uses the full UTF range, and works fine with a number of databases... mySql is the outlier here.